# Split data based on last number of each row name

Tags: r

I would like to create a list by splitting my current data by number in row name.

This is a vector of names:

```
> dput(vec_exp)
c("Mark_0_1", "Mark_0_2", "Mark_0_3", "Mark_10_1", "Mark_10_2", 
"Mark_10_3", "Mark_20_1", "Mark_20_2", "Mark_20_3", "Mark_40_1", 
"Mark_40_2", "Mark_40_3", "Greg_0_1", "Greg_0_2", "Greg_0_3", 
"Greg_10_1", "Greg_10_2", "Greg_10_3", "Greg_20_1", "Greg_20_2", 
"Greg_20_3", "Greg_40_1", "Greg_40_2", "Greg_40_3", "Stuart_0_1", 
"Stuart_0_2", "Stuart_0_3", "Stuart_10_1", "Stuart_10_2", "Stuart_10_3", 
"Stuart_20_1", "Stuart_20_2", "Stuart_20_3", "Stuart_40_1", "Stuart_40_2", 
"Stuart_40_3", "Ian_0_1", "Ian_0_2", "Ian_0_3", "Ian_10_1", "Ian_10_2", 
"Ian_10_3", "Ian_20_1", "Ian_20_2", "Ian_20_3", "Ian_40_1", "Ian_40_2", 
"Ian_40_3", "Hugh_0_1", "Hugh_0_2", "Hugh_0_3", "Hugh_10_1", 
"Hugh_10_2", "Hugh_10_3", "Hugh_20_1", "Hugh_20_2", "Hugh_20_3", 
"Hugh_40_1", "Hugh_40_2", "Hugh_40_3", "Carl_0_1", "Carl_0_2", 
"Carl_0_3", "Carl_10_1", "Carl_10_2", "Carl_10_3", "Carl_20_1", 
"Carl_20_2", "Carl_20_3", "Carl_40_1", "Carl_40_2", "Carl_40_3", 
"Mark_0_4", "Mark_0_5", "Mark_0_6", "Mark_10_4", "Mark_10_5", 
"Mark_10_6", "Mark_20_4", "Mark_20_5", "Mark_20_6", "Mark_40_4", 
"Mark_40_5", "Mark_40_6", "Greg_0_4", "Greg_0_5", "Greg_0_6", 
"Greg_10_4", "Greg_10_5", "Greg_10_6", "Greg_20_4", "Greg_20_5", 
"Greg_20_6", "Greg_40_4", "Greg_40_5", "Greg_40_6", "Stuart_0_4", 
"Stuart_0_5", "Stuart_0_6", "Stuart_10_4", "Stuart_10_5", "Stuart_10_6", 
"Stuart_20_4", "Stuart_20_5", "Stuart_20_6", "Stuart_40_4", "Stuart_40_5", 
"Stuart_40_6", "Ian_0_4", "Ian_0_5", "Ian_0_6", "Ian_10_4", "Ian_10_5", 
"Ian_10_6", "Ian_20_4", "Ian_20_5", "Ian_20_6", "Ian_40_4", "Ian_40_5", 
"Ian_40_6", "Hugh_0_4", "Hugh_0_5", "Hugh_0_6", "Hugh_10_4", 
"Hugh_10_5", "Hugh_10_6", "Hugh_20_4", "Hugh_20_5", "Hugh_20_6", 
"Hugh_40_4", "Hugh_40_5", "Hugh_40_6", "Carl_0_4", "Carl_0_5", 
"Carl_0_6", "Carl_10_4", "Carl_10_5", "Carl_10_6", "Carl_20_4", 
"Carl_20_5", "Carl_20_6", "Carl_40_4", "Carl_40_5", "Carl_40_6", 
"Mark_0_7", "Mark_0_8", "Mark_0_9", "Mark_10_7", "Mark_10_8", 
"Mark_10_9", "Mark_20_7", "Mark_20_8", "Mark_20_9", "Mark_40_7", 
"Mark_40_8", "Mark_40_9", "Greg_0_7", "Greg_0_8", "Greg_0_9", 
"Greg_10_7", "Greg_10_8", "Greg_10_9", "Greg_20_7", "Greg_20_8", 
"Greg_20_9", "Greg_40_7", "Greg_40_8", "Greg_40_9", "Stuart_0_7", 
"Stuart_0_8", "Stuart_0_9", "Stuart_10_7", "Stuart_10_8", "Stuart_10_9", 
"Stuart_20_7", "Stuart_20_8", "Stuart_20_9", "Stuart_40_7", "Stuart_40_8", 
"Stuart_40_9", "Ian_0_7", "Ian_0_8", "Ian_0_9", "Ian_10_7", "Ian_10_8", 
"Ian_10_9", "Ian_20_7", "Ian_20_8", "Ian_20_9", "Ian_40_7", "Ian_40_8", 
"Ian_40_9", "Hugh_0_7", "Hugh_0_8", "Hugh_0_9", "Hugh_10_7", 
"Hugh_10_8", "Hugh_10_9", "Hugh_20_7", "Hugh_20_8", "Hugh_20_9", 
"Hugh_40_7", "Hugh_40_8", "Hugh_40_9", "Carl_0_7", "Carl_0_8", 
"Carl_0_9", "Carl_10_7", "Carl_10_8", "Carl_10_9", "Carl_20_7", 
"Carl_20_8", "Carl_20_9", "Carl_40_7", "Carl_40_8", "Carl_40_9", 
"Mark_0_10", "Mark_0_11", "Mark_0_12", "Mark_0_13", "Mark_10_10", 
"Mark_10_11", "Mark_10_12", "Mark_10_13", "Mark_20_10", "Mark_20_11", 
"Mark_20_12", "Mark_20_13", "Mark_40_10", "Mark_40_11", "Mark_40_12", 
"Mark_40_13", "Greg_0_10", "Greg_0_11", "Greg_0_12", "Greg_0_13", 
"Greg_10_10", "Greg_10_11", "Greg_10_12", "Greg_10_13", "Greg_20_10", 
"Greg_20_11", "Greg_20_12", "Greg_20_13", "Greg_40_10", "Greg_40_11", 
"Greg_40_12", "Greg_40_13", "Stuart_0_10", "Stuart_0_11", "Stuart_0_12", 
"Stuart_0_13", "Stuart_10_10", "Stuart_10_11", "Stuart_10_12", 
"Stuart_10_13", "Stuart_20_10", "Stuart_20_11", "Stuart_20_12", 
"Stuart_20_13", "Stuart_40_10", "Stuart_40_11", "Stuart_40_12", 
"Stuart_40_13", "Ian_0_10", "Ian_0_11", "Ian_0_12", "Ian_0_13", 
"Ian_10_10", "Ian_10_11", "Ian_10_12", "Ian_10_13", "Ian_20_10", 
"Ian_20_11", "Ian_20_12", "Ian_20_13", "Ian_40_10", "Ian_40_11", 
"Ian_40_12", "Ian_40_13", "Hugh_0_10", "Hugh_0_11", "Hugh_0_12", 
"Hugh_0_13", "Hugh_10_10", "Hugh_10_11", "Hugh_10_12", "Hugh_10_13", 
"Hugh_20_10", "Hugh_20_11", "Hugh_20_12", "Hugh_20_13", "Hugh_40_10", 
"Hugh_40_11", "Hugh_40_12", "Hugh_40_13", "Carl_0_10", "Carl_0_11", 
"Carl_0_12", "Carl_0_13", "Carl_10_10", "Carl_10_11", "Carl_10_12", 
"Carl_10_13", "Carl_20_10", "Carl_20_11", "Carl_20_12", "Carl_20_13", 
"Carl_40_10", "Carl_40_11", "Carl_40_12", "Carl_40_13")
```

I would like to group all of these names based on number after last `_`. It means there will be 13 groups.

I would like to use a code below for splitting, so only pattern is missing:

```
DF = split(DF_to_split,gsub("XXXXXXXXXX",rownames(DF_to_split)))
```

Of course we can use different code for splitting but output from this one fits well for firther code.

Comment: You could use: `gsub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", rownames(DF_to_split))`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything until last underscore :

```
split(vec_exp, sub('.*_', '', vec_exp))
```

You can replace the pattern in your code.

```
DF = split(DF_to_split,sub('.*_', '', rownames(DF_to_split)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe where the included vector is a variable you can try this (`v1` is the provided data):

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(v1=v1,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Extract last character
df$v2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$v1, split = '_'), function(x) x[length(x)])
#Split
List <- split(df,df$v2)
List <- lapply(List,function(x) {x$v2<-NULL;return(x)})
```

Output:

```
List[[1]]
            v1
1     Mark_0_1
4    Mark_10_1
7    Mark_20_1
10   Mark_40_1
13    Greg_0_1
16   Greg_10_1
19   Greg_20_1
22   Greg_40_1
25  Stuart_0_1
28 Stuart_10_1
31 Stuart_20_1
34 Stuart_40_1
37     Ian_0_1
40    Ian_10_1
43    Ian_20_1
46    Ian_40_1
49    Hugh_0_1
52   Hugh_10_1
55   Hugh_20_1
58   Hugh_40_1
61    Carl_0_1
64   Carl_10_1
67   Carl_20_1
70   Carl_40_1
```

You will get a list (`List`) of 13 elements.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_extract_last` from `stringi` to extract the last digits and then `split`

```
library(stringi)   
grp <- stri_extract_last_regex(vec_exp, "\\d+")
split(DF_to_split, grp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern:

```
sub(".*_(.*)", "\\1", vec_exp)
```

If you are not familiar with the regular expressions, you can try `word()` from `stringr`.

```
stringr::word(vec_exp, -1, sep = "_")
```

Both of them give:

```
# [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1" 
# [14] "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "2"
# ...
# [300] "13" "10" "11" "12" "13" "10" "11" "12" "13" "10" "11" "12" "13"
```